# VSTS deploy Azure function error: 4294967295

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, webdeploy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using VSTS to deploy an Azure Function. I started getting some errors during the deployment from yesterday morning.

The error code is **4294967295**, usually related to a locked folder but the error message says **The user name or password is incorrect**, so I'm a little confused.

```
2018-01-28T08:31:58.6556754Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2018-01-28T08:31:58.6568081Z ##[error]Error: (1/28/2018 8:31:58 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Error: The user name or password is incorrect.

   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirectoryEx.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirectoryEx.CreateDirectoriesFromRoot(String path)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AppOfflineRuleHandler.AddAppOfflineFilesToEachApp(DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Boolean whatIf)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AppOfflineRuleHandler.Add(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject& sourceObject, Boolean& proceed)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAdd(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable1 passId, String user, String siteName)
Error count: 1.

2018-01-28T08:31:58.6575553Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
```

Comment: Can you show the whole build/release log for the Azure App Service Deploy task by setting `system.debug` = `true`? And what's the agent did you used?

Comment: Hi @marina, [here](https://pastebin.com/6XzAWQfR) you can find the Azure App Service Deploy task logs with `system.debug = true`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log, the **Package or folder option** for Azure App Service Deploy task is too broad. It matches more than one `.zip` files.

In the log, it matches two zip files:

```
d:\a\r1\a\Stamp BigBro\drop\HeartbeatMonitor.zip
d:\a\r1\a\temp_web_package_08951874997805498.zip
```

And the `d:\a\r1\a\temp_web_package_08951874997805498.zip` file(apparently it’s not as expected) is treated as package in `msdeploy` cli.

So you should change the Package or folder option to make sure it can only much the HeartbeatMonitor.zip fie. Such as any of below formats can work:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\HeartbeatMonitor.zip
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Stamp BigBro\drop\HeartbeatMonitor.zip
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Marina, it's already like you suggested. Package or Folder is set like this: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Stamp BigBro\drop\HeartbeatMonitor.zip.It seems like that if I delete the Azure Function and I create it again, the deploy works the first time but the second time I get the same error.

Comment: What if you use `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\HeartbeatMonitor.zip` instead?

Comment: The problem is still there also with `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\HeartbeatMonitor.zip`. Checking the logs a little better I saw `temp_web_package_08951874997805498.zip` is created by VSTS. VSTS unzips `HeartbeatMonitor.zip` to a temp directory, and then zip it again, that's why msdeploy is deploying a `temp_web_package_08951874997805498.zip`